# use javascript to access local couchdb

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I recently met a problem when using javascript to access local CouchDB (127.0.0.1:5984).
My code is attached below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CouchDB jQuery Examples</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="/_utils/script/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="/_utils/script/sha1.js"></script>
    <script src="/_utils/script/jquery.js?1.4.2"></script>
    <script src="/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js?0.11.0"></script>
    <script src="/_utils/script/jquery.dialog.js?0.11.0"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    function initialize(){
        $.get("http://127.0.0.1:5984/test", function(data, status){
            window.alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    }
</script>
<body onload="initialize()">
</body>
</html>
```

I tried my local txt file and it works. But when I tried to access my local CouchDB database called test, and it returns nothing. I have no idea why this will happen.
BTW, I also tried the "http://127.0.0.1:5984/test?callback=?" but the result is the same.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution to it yet?